# Catching parameters in redirect with Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, parameters, gatsby

I have one quick and dirt question.

Is it possible to catch a query parameter from a server redirect inside of Gatsby.js application?

We have a Pardot tracking link that does redirect to our thank you page which is built in Gatsby.js and I want to pass some query parameters to the application it self from that redirect.

So for example:

```
www.trackedlink.com/thank-you?programme_code=CODE_FROM_REDIRECT_ON_SERVERSIDE
```

will redirect to:

```
www.gatsbyapplicationthatwillreadthequery.com/thank-you?programme_code=CODE_FROM_REDIRECT_ON_SERVERSIDE
```

Is it possible to read that query inside of the application if it's coming from the outside of the app?

Cheers and have a great week!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are triggered in the client-side the redirection will be caught by the application and yes, it would possible if they are coming from outside the app or using a standard anchor. Not using a `@reach/router` (`<Link>` component since it's a limitation).

A clean and scalable way to use it is by adding in the function in your `gatsby-browser.js` configuration:

```
import React from 'react';
import { checkUrlFunction } from './src/services/yourCheckUrlFunction';

export const onClientEntry = () => checkUrlFunction();
```

Adding a function in [`gatsby-browser.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/) with `onClientEntry` API will trigger your function once the page is loaded. From the documentation:

> `onClientEntry Function (_: emptyArg, pluginOptions: pluginOptions) => undefined`
>  Called when the Gatsby browser runtime first starts.

Your function should look like:

```js
   export const checkUrlFunction = () => {
         if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
           const queryString = window.location.search;
           const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
           const programmeCode= urlParams.get('programme_code')

           if(programmeCode) window.localStorage.setItem('programmeCode', programmeCode)

           console.log(programmeCode); // will output CODE_FROM_REDIRECT_ON_SERVERSIDE      
         };
       };
```

*Note the `typeof window !== 'undefined'` necessary to avoid issues if the [`window` object is not defined when triggering the function](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/)*

---

> Hi Ferran, thank you for your solution but unfortunately, it does not
> work when the redirect happens. It only works if the query string is
> inside of the application

Yes, the idea of adding the function in `gatsby-browser.js` is to avoid the addition of `checkUrlFunction()` in each page, template, or component. The disadvantage is that you lose a bit of control but it saves **a lot** of overwriting code and improves the scalability and readability.

---

> Thanks, Ferran, if you could show me an example of it - it would be
> amazing! This cookie topic is sort of unknown water for me

So, with your specifications updated, I've added the `localStorage` approach since it's easier to achieve in a non-IDE environment like this, but the idea is exactly the same.

- Set a vault (`cookie` or `localStorage`) automated in the `gatsby-browser.js` function

  ```
  if(programmeCode) window.localStorage.setItem('programmeCode', programmeCode)
  ```

This sets a localStorage key/value pair (`'programmeCode'` (key)/`programmeCode` (value)

- Access to that vault in your component. Use a `componentDidMount` lifecycle or `useEffect` hook to ensure that is loaded before the DOM tree is mounted.

  ```
  useEffect(()=>{
   if(typeof window !== undefined) console.log(window.location.getItem('programmeCode')
  }, [])
  ```

Comment: Hi Ferran, that is amazing! Thank you! 
How would I access the programmeCode now inside of some other component?

Comment: In that case, you need to call for `checkUrlFunction` in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle or `useEffect` hook. Because using `gatsby-browser.js` will automate the process of triggering it in each component but if you need to access it in a certain component, you should call it manually.

Comment: Ok great, shouldn't I call onClientEntry? Since checkUrlFunction needs to go through onClientEntry in order to give me the programme code, otherwise it gives me undefined

Comment: Yes if you need to play or use your parameter in a component, you should call it in your component. Another approach that may work for you, is to set a `cookie` or localStorage in your `checkUrlFunction` based on the URL parameter and get that `cookie` or `localStorage` in your component. Whatever fits better your needs. I will update my answer based on that.

Comment: Hi Ferran, thank you for your solution but unfortunately, it does not work when the redirect happens. It only works if the query string is inside of the application.

Comment: The window object sees only the current page, it does not see the url that it got redirected from, unfortunately. Do you think there could be a workaround for that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a `localStorage` approach. Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: Brilliant, 1 thing again ( I'm sorry ) - onClientEntry happens when initial Gatsby runtime starts and therefore it sees only the current URL and it doesn't see the URL that it got redirected from so I can't catch any parameters from that first URL that is not a Gatsby Application.

Comment: Yes exactly. If the original URL is not caught by your Gatsby application you won't be able to get it using any JavaScript code rendered in the client-side.

Comment: Do you think there could be a workaround for that? Some way to see what the initial URL was or to get that parameter from the URL outside of Gatsby application

Comment: If the initial URL doesn't belong to Gatsby app, it's server-side work :/